# Python problem with import curses.ascii.*

Tags: python, django, python-import, python-curses, isalpha

I am using Python 2.5 in Windows and I am trying import `curses.ascii.*` to a django project.

Code: `from curses.ascii import *`

Error: `No module named _curses`.

Any suggestion?

By the way, the only function I need to use is `isalpha()`...

Comment: If this is on Windows, I don't think curses is supported by Python 2.5.

Comment: Next question is why you are trying to use curses on windows ;)

Comment: I need to use `isalpha()` only :)

Comment: strings already have an isalpha method. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say which platform you are on, but there is probably a package which will install the curses bindings for you.

In debian/ubuntu for example it is part of the default python install

If you built the Python yourself, you may be missing the libcurses-dev

If you are on windows maybe check out [this wcurses package](http://adamv.com/dev/python/curses/)
Otherwise curses is [not supported](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6.2/howto/curses.html) on windows however there is a [Console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) module

Edit: since the OP is just using `isalpha`

Strings have their own isalpha() method already

```
>>> "Hello".isalpha()
True
>>> "World!".isalpha()
False
```

The one with curses only works on single characters

```
>>> from curses.ascii import isalpha
>>> all(isalpha(x) for x in "Hello")
True
>>> all(isalpha(x) for x in "World!")
False
```

Comment: Yay, still forget that everything is object... it works thanks :)